# Use of こうして in this sentence

Tags: grammar

Can someone please explain which part of this sentence こうして is modifying and how it is changing the meaning of the sentence:

> 鴫｛しぎ｝を見るために、行ったことはあったが、暑い季節に**こうして**弁当まで持っていくのは初めてである。

Without こうして I translate this as

> I have been to see the sandpipers before, but this is my first time bringing a lunch along in the hot season.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「こうして」 modifies the whole verb phrase 「弁当{べんとう}まで持{も}っていく」.

It is saying that they have been to the place before, but it is the first time that they have gone there by even bringing a lunch ***like this*** in the hot season.